# POST request via Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have an API endpoint that I can access in Python like this:

```
headers = {
    "x-api-key": "xxx",
    }

    json_data = {
        "limit": 2000,
            "timePeriod": 24,
        }
}
response = requests.post('https://api-query.de/queryapi/v2/searchingjson/name', 
        headers=headers, json=json_data)
```

I can then extract json from the response. Now, I am trying to recreate this setup in Foundry. I created a custom data connection:

YAML:

```
type: magritte-rest-v2
sourceMap:
  my_api:
    type: magritte-rest-auth-call-source
    url: https://api-query.de/
    headers:
      x-api-key: '{{x_api_key}}'
    authCalls:
      - type: magritte-rest-call
        path: /queryapi/v2/searchingjson/name
        method: POST
        extractor:
          - type: magritte-rest-json-extractor
```

Then I created a Sync:
[image]

However, the Sync fails and I get error messages like this:

```
ServiceException: CUSTOM_CLIENT (MagritteRestSource:InvalidResponseStatus): {responseCode=403, validCodes=[200, 201, 204], response={"message":"Forbidden"}, filename=[hidden]#2023-01-20T11_06_14.182265Z}
```

It says forbidden so i am guessing i am not passing in the API key properly. What else can I try?

I also tried adding an optional header (a key value pair for the api key) in the Sync but that didn't work either. But anyhow, that should not be used because there is no encryption for the key in this option

Comment: Have you considered external transforms, instead of magritte rest? https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/external-transforms/

Answer (score 1):

The `authCalls:` part in the yaml is not required, since you already have an api key. This would be required if for example you need to do an oauth2-flow.

Please remove that part from the YAML and try again.

Comment: what about the body? is it supposed to go in both places (sync, YAML) or just one?

Comment: My answer contains the minimum required changes to make this work. The body is usually defined in the Sync, not the source.